# Bashrc alias for deleting non consecutive duplicate lines directly from file then save and close it

Tags: bash, shell

`alias v='vim -esu NONE +'g/\v^(.+)$\_.{-}^\1$/d''`
Will delete the duplicate lines from the input file and will `:wq` it also.
I want to create alias for this but it giving error
`syntax error near unexpected token`('`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In shell you cannot nest single quotes inside a pair of single quotes.

You can either use:

```
alias v="vim -esu NONE +'g/\v^(.+)$\_.{-}^\1$/d'"
```

or better use a function instead of `alias` without worrying about quoting:

```
v() { vim -esu NONE +'g/\v^(.+)$\_.{-}^\1$/d'; }
```

Comment: If I create alias I am getting error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `.+'`

Comment: Do `unalias v` first and then try declaring function

Comment: Thanks it worked. alias is "vim -esu NONE +'g/\v^(.+)$\_.{-}^\1$/d' +wq".  Added +wq to save and close it. Its taking too much time for the file having only 6 lines. Any other way to make it fast serving same purpose .

Comment: If file is in /users/username/ then its going in infinite loop and other places working fine. Any idea why ?

Comment: That's totally weird, may be some permission issues in that directory.. otherwise there is no problem